# How to apply scroll for table body in ng2-smart-table using angular 2

Tags: scrollbar, vertical-scrolling, ng2-smart-table

I'm using ng2-smart-table which is having 19 columns, it is going out of the frame in the dashboard. So I need to apply horizontal scroll to the table body.

Am using ng2-smart-table in my angular 2 project

```
:host /deep/ table {
  width: 1200px !important;
  overflow-x: scroll;

}
```

Am not getting the horizontal scroll for the table

Comment: Please reply for this post.

Comment: Nobody knows or what? At least say that.....

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
<div class="col-md-12" style = "overflow-x: scroll;">
     <div class="smart-table-container" style = "width: 2000px;">
          <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source"></ng2-smart-table>  
     </div>
 </div>
```